# While loop incrementing array length

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Can someone please help me understand why the following array length increments without having a counter.

```
var inputName = "";
var namesArray = new Array();

while ( (inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "")) != "") {
    namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName;
}

namesArray.sort();

var namesList = namesArray.join("\n");

console.log(namesList);
```

So from this I am assuming, a while loop increments any value you include inside the while loop. I had a look at [MDN While Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and I can see that both the x in this example is also incrementing.

I just want to be sure that I got this correct but mainly understand why it does this.

Thanks

Comment: the length is not a counter... once you put data in the array, the size increases

Comment: Doing assigment directly in the while loop, is generally not very good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an empty array, `length` property will be `0`. Let's put it like this

1st iteration

```
while ( (inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "")) != "") {
    namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName;
    // namesArray[0] = inputName;
}
```

2nd iteration

```
while ( (inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "")) != "") {
    namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName;
    // namesArray[1] = inputName; // since now length is 1
}
```

And so on.. So what you're doing is assigning in following fashion

```
names[0] = inputName
names[1] = inputName 
...
```

So, the `length` increases from `0` to `n` as you're adding elements to the Array.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I like answers like this where examples are provided.

Comment: @KamMiah ah! glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an item into an array can be done in several ways in Javascript

your code essentially does a push, so you could replace

```
namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName
```

with

```
namesArray.push(inputName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The length property of a Javascript array is the highest subscript plus one.  So, if there are eight elements in an array, they have indices 0 - 7 and length is 8.  The assignment statement, `namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName;` adds an element to the array, and so increases the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while (condition) {// Condition either return true or false so loop will execute untill condition return false
     namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName //you just push data into array
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer in order to add a context to the code (the comments are ok but it's not sufficient).